# Symbol to indicate the absence of an attribute

Tags: symbols

I want to compare some objects with a defined metric.
Let's say object A offers an attribute and object B does not.
I then want to give an overview in a table.

Object A would get a `\checkmark`, that's easy.

But for object B I'm totally unsure whether I should use

1. `$\otimes$`
2. `\texttimes`
3. no symbol at all

[image]

to indicate that object B does **NOT** have the attribute.
I'm not happy with the `times-`symbols because, well, they should be used for mathematical reasons.

What do you think?

Comment: An em-dash `---` could also be a possibility.

Comment: Good suggestion, guess I will go with it. If you post this as an answer I'm going to accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possibility is to use an em-dash:

[image]

The code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{bbding}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabular}{lcc}
\toprule
 & ObjectA & ObjectB \\
\midrule
Attribute1 & \Checkmark & --- \\
Attribute2 & --- & \Checkmark \\
Attribute3 & \Checkmark & --- \\
\bottomrule 
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```